# Bundle library for two architectures in the same package

Tags: packaging, shared-library

I need to ship a Racket package that is cross compatible on x86 and arm.  I have a shared library I depend on via FFI that I would like to bundle in, so that the user doesn't need to install it.

What is the convention for this?  Are there specific directories under /usr/lib dedicated to different architectures?  Should I just keep it installed with my package and find a way to link dynamically to the correct architecture library within my FFI?  Something else?  My ideal would be to install everything and not rely on the dynamic linker to link to the correct version instead of having to do that myself.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. For what OS or Linux distribution do you create the package in what package format? Where do you install the files? Is your software some multi-arch binary or written in an interpreted language? What shared lib does your software depend on? If this is a library that is available as a package for the OS, you should not try to install it at the same location. You could put the libraries in a package specific directory, maybe somethink like `/usr/lib/yourpackage/arm-linux-gnueabihf` or `.../x86_64-linux-gnu` etc. or in `/opt/yourpackage/...`